# Determining response time for IIS requests

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

We have a web service that is called by a third party.  Third party's rules are that the service must return a response within 10 seconds.

We log all of the processing time, from when we receive the request, to when the web method exits.

Our problem: our third party is telling us that we are taking over 10 seconds, but according to our logs, we are finished processing well within time limit.

I suspect that the third party is having a connectivity problem, and that the time is lost after we complete processing, but while the response is coming down the wire.  Our in-application logging can't captuer that timing (that I know of) because our web method has already returned.

Is there any IIS logging feature that we could use capture the time spent returning the response?

Comment: If you use a Stopwatch to measure the execution time of your web method and it's well under the limit, then don't look in IIS for problems. It's more likely a network layer, not an application layer  issue at that point.

Comment: @Icarus You're right, but that's exactly what I'm trying to diagnose -- right now I suspect that's the problem due to absence of evidence in my logs.  I'm looking for an IIS log that would show me how much time was spent transfering the response over the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time-taken entry in your logs accounts for the time it takes for the client to send the acknowledgment back to the server or reset the connection.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mike/archive/2008/11/13/time-vs-time-taken-fields-in-iis-logging.aspx

You'll want to also make use of the win32-status to determine when there is an issue.